# Dynamically Generating Divs with jQuery based on variable number

Tags: jquery

Alright I'm a little lost.

I've a page that pulls a value out of a database which is then being loaded into a variable, ticketNum. Basically I just need to generate the same div/content every time based on this number. I'm at a loss as it how to do it.

If the ticketNum is 10, I need 10 divs, if it's 3, I need 3 and so on.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var ticketNum = 10;

 if (ticketNum > 0) {

   } else {

   }

});
```

Comment: Try to do this using your server-side language if possible.

Comment: Why should they try to do it via a server side language? Just simple dom manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/a_re-introduction_to_javascript#Control_structures):

```
if (ticketNum > 0) {
    for (i=0; i < ticketNum; i++) {
        $('<div id="addedDiv_num' + i + '" />').text('Div number:  ' + i).appendTo('#containerElement');
    }
}
```

[JS FIddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2fEML/).

Comment: Awesome thanks. I know this was probably dead simple for ya, but as designer dabbling in dev it's a huge help.

Comment: @OD_WebDev: no problem at all (we all started learning something *at least* once...) =)

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/5KHaq/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var ticketNum = 10;

    for(var i = 0; i<ticketNum;i++){
        $('<div></div>').appendTo('#container').text("Div number " + i);   
    }
});
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Our answers are, essentially, the same: so +1 =)

Comment: heh yeah, we just happen to hit submit at roughly the same time.